# Enum as generic param, enforce secondary type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type-safe method of assigning secondary keys to an object, depending on the value of a primary type (which is currently an enum). I tried the following, but the type `Test` is typed as `string` instead of an union of allowed values. How can I achieve this?

```
export enum PrimaryImageType {
  Artnum = "ARTNUM",
  RMA = "RMA",
}

export const SecondaryImageTypes: Record<PrimaryImageType, string[]> = {
  [PrimaryImageType.Artnum]: [
    "LDA_OVP",
    "LDA_PALETTE",
    "LDA_LABEL",
    "LDA_VERPACKHINWEIS",
    "LDA_MASTERKARTON",
  ],
  RMA: [
  ],
};

export type SecondaryType<P extends PrimaryImageType> = typeof SecondaryImageTypes[P][number];

type Test =  SecondaryType<PrimaryImageType.Artnum>;
//   Test is typed as string, I expect it to be "LDA_OVP" | "LDA_PALETTE" | "LDA_LABEL" | "LDA_VERPACKHINWEIS" | "LDA_MASTERKARTON"


// I want to use those types similar to this:
export interface Image<P extends PrimaryImageType> {
  id: number,
  imageType: P,
  typeID: string,
  secondaryType: SecondaryType<P>,
}

// TS should enforce the union of secondary types:
const testImg: Image<PrimaryImageType.Artnum> = {
  id: 1,
  imageType: PrimaryImageType.Artnum,
  typeID: "asd",
  secondaryType: "INVALID", // should be invalid
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwApQJaoIZQCeAkvgObAAqhYwcA3gFBxwCCsK6AvHAESsAlSgDkAqgFleAGmZwB41nB695raYwC+jRqEiw4AYwiIAzvADKwI4gAmBEuSo1gJgFxyr0GwB4sue6R4FNS0UnBmOIhkANoAugB8Sgyy0X74RIHBzgB07DCcse7Rsiy8ADIAIqwA+gDyAGoY6iyllTUYrGUAopSUXc0t5VXVZawAQl1lA63D9V0CHQDCANIAEsTCAOpdxObTfG3VCuZ9AsuClLXCA7EyLKpFsreaANzautDwMM5wltZ2RBCwF8CBAMCQNhMmBw6QcQSctESPG+tAgADNfp5bAFHECTKlYtFOAAjYBQWJvRgouiUFzwHiY-72IG+GE4+FA3IcNDxN4Aej5LVpZjg2Ch1JscDwUIi2CiYWIoNoBng2C+EDgpIOwwaTTgAB9te1Oj0+rwDUaRuNJubDUManMFqwVustjs9hb7UdWCd5uchFdeNpGAK4IqAO54RDquDIEx0GAACwg8bg1JluGwABsCGmNUmxa4dOBPqLo2S0XgDHRMsCMKDwbYoWl2VlEckWNgbO4SWS7qLcc53Bh+9TiBV3LL5bJ40zAUPGcYAYQWRh4jItCHBZRzOFk8gs5KkGjoNW04m6MhENhjHB0eEscu0843IxrCLwWZSGR3LXWf4MkHWguXyHkkiYTtuzgABGft-DbYBhzZQCORyPJOFHZxx3cXhpRsAZZyXZkF14DZ6k6cdpDgUMTH3Q9NToOUADc8CzLtNCAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8jpw) work for you? Note that it requires [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html), and you may not have it due to ts version. If it works for you, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: We're using TS ^4.9.5, so the `satisfies` operator seems to be the perfect solution, thanks!
I know this is a second question: Is there also a way to infer the PrimaryImageType for the `Image` type, based on the `imageType` field?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the question. Do you mean that you want not to have the `secondaryType` field if the `imageType` is `PrimaryImageType.RMA`?

Comment: No, I meant that I can leave out the generic specifier `<PrimaryImageType.Artnum>` because it's identical to the `imageType`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it will be possible. You may consider turning it into a function. Something like: `getImage({...})`

Comment: no problem, this would warrant a second question here anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see it as `string` because you declared `SecondaryImageTypes` as  `Record<PrimaryImageType, string[]>`, and ts can't narrow the `string` to the literal values that you have used.

The easiest thing to do is to remove the type definition of `SecondaryImageTypes` and [const assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) it:

```
export const SecondaryImageTypes = {
  [PrimaryImageType.Artnum]: [
    'LDA_OVP',
    'LDA_PALETTE',
    'LDA_LABEL',
    'LDA_VERPACKHINWEIS',
    'LDA_MASTERKARTON',
  ],
  RMA: [],
} as const;
```

Doing this will solve your problem, however `SecondaryImageTypes` is not type safe and thanks to [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) we can easily fix it.
Note: `satisfies` was added in Typescript 4.9 so it will not works for the previous versions.

```
export const SecondaryImageTypes = {
  [PrimaryImageType.Artnum]: [
    'LDA_OVP',
    'LDA_PALETTE',
    'LDA_LABEL',
    'LDA_VERPACKHINWEIS',
    'LDA_MASTERKARTON',
  ],
  RMA: [],
} as const satisfies Record<PrimaryImageType, readonly string[]>;
```

```
// type Test = "LDA_OVP" | "LDA_PALETTE" | "LDA_LABEL" | "LDA_VERPACKHINWEIS" | "LDA_MASTERKARTON"
type Test = SecondaryType<PrimaryImageType.Artnum>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=21&ssc=52&pln=20&pc=1#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)